# string into single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the comma separated string as shown below to convert into a column.

**Example**:

Given String:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO'
```

Have to convert into a single column:

```
columnName
-----------
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
```

Comment: Many dups about *splitting* a string; [Tsql split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
Used `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` function to remove Leading and Trailing spaces.

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO'

SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) Split_Data
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@STR, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Split_Data
----------
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Will accept this within 5 min.